# NullPointerExpection after second submit multipart/conf - Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, form-submit

I´m facing a strange behaviour on my development system. After a succesfull FileUpload trough a form multi/part submit, I forward to another Servlet to handle the database insert and from there I redirect to the source page where the file upload got initiated.  If the user now tries to upload another File trough multi/part submit, Tomcat throws a NullPointerException when i try to read the Parameters from the request in the first Servlet.

At first i analyzed the POST from the Client to the server, just to find out that they looked exactly the same.

The obscure thing is, if I reload the page with F5 several times im able to upload another File without problems. Because of this i tried, as a fast fix, to append a random number to the URL and use JAVASCRIPT to force a hard reload once (location.reload(true) but this did not fix the problem at all.

My settings are:

**Tomcat 7.0.55**

**mySql Database (latest release)**

**Java 1.8.0_20**

**Eclipse Juno**

## Programing Code

**documents.jsp**

```
<form id="up_additional" action="../CreateAgentCustomerContractAdditional" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><table id="additional_upload_table">  

<tr>
 <td><input type="hidden" id="contract_id_select" name="contract_id_select"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr>    
 <td class="table_tag_forms">Dokumententyp</td>
 <td class="value_tag_forms"><input type="text" name="doc_type" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>    
 <td class="table_tag_forms">Kommentar</td>
 <td class="value_tag_forms"><textarea name="add_comment"></textarea> </td>
</tr>

<tr>    
 <td class="table_tag_forms">Dokument</td>
 <td class="value_tag_forms"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr><td><input class="change" type="submit" /></td></tr>
</table> 
</form>
```

**CreateAgentCustomerContractAdditional**

```
int contract_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contract_id_select"));
    String comment = request.getParameter("add_comment");
    String doc_type = request.getParameter("doc_type");
```

**....**
**....**

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("//InsertContractAdditional").forward(request, response);
```

**InsertContractAdditional**

```
response.sendRedirect( context_pathprefix + context/documents.jsp?#"+ran.nextDouble());
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
  if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash != "#reloaded" ) {
   window.location.hash =  "reloaded";
   location.reload(true);
  }
};
</script>
```

I hope someone is able to give me an hint!

With kind regards!

**P.S.: StackTrace**

```
HTTP Status 500 - nulltype Exception report

message null

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
servlet.CreateAgentCustomerContractAdditional.doPost(CreateAgentCustomerContractAdditional.java:62)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Appendix**

The value for the hidden Input field is set by an onClick event by the user. In both POSTS the value is filled when i look at the element in debug mode!

```
$('.additional_documents').on('click', function(){ 
 $('#contract_id_select').val($(this).attr('id'));
         display_additional_documents($(this).attr('id'));
         $('#show_additional').show();
     });
```

**THX FOR THE EFFORT SOLVED THE PROBLEM ON MY OWN**

After moving the the application to my productive linux based enviroment and the real Tomcat Webserver it worked like a charm, seems like an Eclipse Bug. Thanks anyway!

Comment: please provide exception details!

Answer (score 0):

When you call location.reload(true) you are making a GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: The Upload is a POST, the location.reload(TRUE) does only happen after the Post is finished when i revisit the side. I tried to simulate a hard F5 but that did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems strange to me:

```
int contract_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contract_id_select"));
```

As in your jsp page you have:

```
<td><input type="hidden" id="contract_id_select" name="contract_id_select"></input></td>
```

I didnt see any value for this field. You are trying to parseInt of null value.

Comment: I appended the code for populating the value, it´s present before I submit. Both times.

Comment: When the user selects a line in a table, and if the ID wouldnt been present there the script would run into an error.

Comment: try to add at this input value="". I'm not sure the value of hidden field is populated before the request is sent to servlet. Also if you said, in debug mode the value is populated, i assume it's an integer format, right?

Comment: Added value="", same story. Yes it´s an integer value, the initial table where the user button is present with the onClick event gets populated from the id column in the database which is autoincrement int. And also if i look into the DOM, before i press the Submit button for the second submit, the value is present there!

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint on CreateAgentCustomerContractAdditional servlet into your IDE and use IDE Debugger to visualize what parameter is coming from "contract_id_select" and please let me know.

Comment: At the second submit i get the NullPointerException, so the values are null.

Comment: So that's the problem. Make sure you assign value at the second submit.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but i figured it out for myself. Moved the application to a productive enviroment and suddenly the problem disappeared without causing any other problems. Seems like a Eclipse Bug.

Answer (score 0):

Better you keep a null check for the parameter 'contract_id_select'.

```
int contract_id = request.getParameter("contract_id_select")==null?-1:Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contract_id_select"));
```